# Issues with php request

Tags: php, ajax, wamp

I have created an application, that requests information using AJAX post method. The information has been encoded with JSON format and passed to my PHP file. On my WAMP server it works perfectly and also works on another dedicated server I have at the office. I was looking to put it up on another server (webhost24), but when I send the data by ajax post request the PHP file receives no data (returns default 0, no values in array).

Could you help me?

**EDIT**

**js file**

```
var uploadStatus = "uploading...";                      //Set value of status
Win('#popSync', 1);                                     //open dialog window
var JSONdepot = JSON.stringify(depots);                 //JSON stringify depots
var JSONcomm = JSON.stringify(Comm);                    //JSON stringify Comm
var JSONreport = JSON.stringify(report);                //JSON stringify report
var JSONevents = JSON.stringify(events);                //JSON stringify events
alert("This is JSON DEPOT: " + depots);
$('#loader').html('<img src="themes/images/301.gif">'); //Set ajax loader
$('#loaderHead').html('<h1>Events synchronizing</h1>'); //Provide header
$('#uploadStatus').html(uploadStatus);                  //set text to status of sync

        $.ajax({                                                                                                    //Ajax comand to connect pass information to syncdata.php file
            type: "POST",                                                                                           //Type: post
            url: "syncdata.php",                                                                                    //URL of file http://sersa.gmi.app should be included when building appliction
            data: {depot: JSONdepot, techname: techsname, comm: JSONcomm, report: JSONreport, events: JSONevents}   //pass depot, techsname, report, and events to url
        })
            .done(function(data){               //When completed
                $('#uploadStatus').html(data);
                if(data >0){                    //If data returns a number greater than zero

                setTimeout(function () {        //set time out of 2 seconds
                        $('#loaderHead').html('<h1>Events synchronized</h1>');          //Set header
                        $('#loader').html('<img src="themes/images/complete.png">');    //Change ajax loader to commpleted 'tick'
                        $('#uploadStatus').html(data + " events synchronized");         //provide how many events have been synced
                        CommRemove();                                                   //clear related information
                        DepotRemove();
                        CHNoRemove();
                        DeleteReportLocal();
                        depots = [];
                        Comm = [];
                        report = [];
                        tempComm = [];
                    }, 2000);
                }

            })
            .fail(function(){
                alert("Something went wrong.<br>ER: SY01");                                //If failed, provide message
            });
```

**PHP File**

```
$depot =json_decode($_POST['depot']);      //Tried $_POST aswell... still same issue
$comm = json_decode($_REQUEST['comm']);    //$_REQUEST doesn't work.. turns out blank
$report = json_decode($_REQUEST['report']);
$events = json_decode($_REQUEST['events']);
$tech = $_REQUEST['techname'];
$depotLength=count($depot);                //Counts return 0
$commLength=count($comm);
$reportLength=count($report);
$eventLength=count($events);
echo "this is Depot: " . $depotLength;     //Returns 0
```

Comment: Not unless you post some actual code

Comment: turn on ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); and see what error it gives.

Comment: Code added, have tried you answers Saqueib.. no joy.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this to get all POST Data:

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

and then decode it.

```
$json= json_decode($postdata,true);
```